# How to exclude abstract typescript class from external library correctly

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I've a external library stored in our gitlab with the following two files:

```js
export default abstract class Client{
   protected someProperty: string | undefined;
   protected static get baseUrl(): string {
       
        return 'www.test.de';
    }
}
```

and the following `index.js`:

```js
//some other exports
export {default as Client} from './src/clients/Client';
```

After installing the lib via npm I tried to consume the base class as follows:

```js
import {Client} from 'my-external-library';

public class MyClient extends Client{
    public static async getIndex(){
        let url = this.baseUrl + '/somepath';
    }
}
```

When I now install the lib in my project and want to work with the base class I get the error message `TS2339 Property 'baseUrl'` does not exist on type 'MyClient'.

How can I export the Client base class correctly that I can consume it without any error messages?

Expect for the error message, the code works as expected.

In addition to that, when I try to access the property `someProperty` after instantiating the class `MyClient` I also get the error message:

```
let myClient = new MyClient();
let test = myClient.someProperty
```

How can I access the property of the abstract class `Client`?

### Update

Having the abstract class in my main project I'm able to access the property of my abstract class but having it in my external lib this class seems not be recognized so that I get the "Property does not exist exception" by following code:

```
let myClient = new MyClient();
let test = myClient.someProperty
```

Is it because of the `export { default as Client} from './src/clients/Client';` ?

Comment: It is static, so it does not exist on the instance `this`

Answer (score 0):

You are making two mistakes on your code:

1. Firstly, you are trying to invoke a static getter using `this`. The correct way to referrence a static property from a member function is `this.constructor.baseUrl`.
2. Secondly, you are using `this` inside a static function. The correct way to call another static function from a static function is to use the class name. In your case it would be: `MyClient.baseUrl`

So your code would work with the following change:

```
import { Client } from 'my-external-library';
    
public class MyClient extends Client {
    public static async getIndex() {
        let url = MyClient.baseUrl + '/somepath';
    }
}
```

---

But I feel that you didn't meant to make the second function static. So if you wanted to make this a member function, you would rewrite it like this:

```
import { Client } from 'my-external-library';

public class MyClient extends Client {
    public async getIndex() {
        let url = this.constructor.baseUrl + '/somepath';
    }
}
```

---

For the second part of your question:

If the property you want to access is a regular property, you can do it exactly as you described:

```
// someProperty is a member property
let myClient = new MyClient();
let test = myClient.someProperty
```

But if the property you want to access is a static property, it can only be accessed through the class, not through the class' instance.

```
// someProperty is a static property
let test = MyClient.someProperty;
```

In your case as I described above, the baseUrl property is a static property.

I think this article would be beneficial for you, it explains the difference between static and regular properties:

https://khalilstemmler.com/blogs/typescript/static-members/

Comment: Great, many thanks. And how can I access a property from "outside" baseClass.someProp = 10 is extended by parentclass.. now I want to access parent.someProp ...

Comment: I'm sorry, can you elaborate a bit more on what you want to do exactly?

Comment: I extended the main question part :)

Comment: @SNO,  Why do you want it static? You could just create an instance. If you want a singleton you could export an instance as `const`

Comment: I just updated my answer to answer the second part of your question.

Comment: @Silvermind I want to have it static because for my fetch request there is no need to have an instance. So in my project I simply can call e.g. await MyClient.FetchResults()

Comment: @SNO, in this case you don't need a class at all to achieve that. But I suppose you are constrained to use the external library, and adapt to this so, I can't object...

Comment: I do use a external library. But around that request I need to do some "preparation" like adding query params, headers etc

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments I did several mistakes.
I removed the inheritances due to the static methods. There is no need for inheritance.

I solved the `property 'xy' does not exist on type`  error message by adding the `.tsconfig` to generate declaration files (`d.ts`) [Link](https://www.tsmean.com/articles/how-to-write-a-typescript-library/).

Now it works.